# Cant Get File Descriptor From Zero MQ ZMQ_SERVER Socket

Tags: c++, zeromq, file-descriptor

I am trying to integrate a ZeroMQ ZMQ_SERVER socket into an an epoll event loop in C++ on Ubuntu. Unfortunately I cannot get the zeromq api to give me a file descriptor. For me he following test method produces an invalid argument error:

```
void test_create_zmq_socket()
{
    std::string address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5558";
    void* socket = zmq_socket(zmq_ctx_new(), ZMQ_SERVER);
    //bind to address
    int error_code = zmq_connect(socket, address.c_str());
    std::cout << "INIT CLIENT SOCKET @ " << address << " STATUS: " << error_code << std::endl;
    if (error_code < 0)
    {
        int error = zmq_errno();
        std::cout << "ZMQ ERROR " << zmq_strerror(error) << std::endl;
        assert(error_code >= 0);
    }

    size_t temp = 4;
    int file_descriptor;
    int error = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_FD, &file_descriptor, &temp);

    if (error < 0)
    {
        int errorno_val = zmq_errno();
        std::cout << "ZMQ ERROR " << zmq_strerror(errorno_val) << std::endl;
        assert(error >= 0);
    }
    std::cout << "FD VAL " << file_descriptor << std::endl;
}
```

The code snippet above prints the following output:

```
ExamplesREPL: 
core/message_handlers/ZMQTest.cpp:36: void core::message_handlers::test_create_zmq_socket(): Assertion `error >= 0' failed.
INIT CLIENT SOCKET @ tcp://127.0.0.1:5558 STATUS: 0
ZMQ ERROR Invalid argument

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I can get the socket to send and receive messages so the socket isn't completely non-functioning.

I am using ZMQ Version 4.2

Comment: Are you on a 64bit system? Is it possible the call is expecting a 64bit integer? Have you tried : size_t temp = sizeof(file_descriptor)

Comment: I am using a 64bit os, Following your suggestion I have tried 8 16, 32 and 64 bit integer types just to be sure and they all produce the same error message. The docs for the zmqapi indicate that the file descriptor return value is a 32bit integer. The above code works for other types of ZMQ sockets (ie if you change the socket type from ZMQ_SERVER to ZMQ_DEALER the code returns a valid file descriptor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading I found out that you cant retrieve a file descriptor for any of the thread safe sockets, you must instead use the new zeromq poller. This poller also accepts file descriptors from other sources thus allowing them to be integrated into the event loop. There is an example in the tests folder of the zeromq source code which demonstrates this functionality.